# Why does Microsoft Barcode Control break when the workbook is opened via interop?

Tags: excel, vb.net, activex, office-interop

I have a worksheet, to which I have added a QR code.

The QR code is an ActiveX control: Microsoft Barcode Control 14.0

The QR code is linked to a cell (A1), so that when the value in the cell changes, so does the QR code.

When I open the workbook normally, everything works as it should.

However, when I open it using Interop from a vb.net Winforms project, the QR code no longer responds when the value in the linked cell changes. 
Whats more, when I right click on the barcode control, the "Microsoft Barcode Control 14.0 Object" context menu option (seen below) is missing.

[image]

The interop code that I am using to open the workbook is as follows:

```
Dim XLApp As New Excel.Application
XLApp.Visible = True
Dim XLBook As Excel.Workbook = XLApp.Workbooks.Open(FilePath)
```

Can anyone tell me what is causing this to happen? And perhaps suggest what I can do to prevent it happening.

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/enable-or-disable-activex-settings-in-office-files-f1303e08-a3f8-41c5-a17e-b0b8898743ed

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you for the suggestion, however, I have gone into the "ActiveX Settings" and enabled all controls. Unless I am missing some setting somewhere (entirely possible). But even if I have, why does it work when opening it manually, but not when opened via interop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not get the Microsoft Barcode Control to function correctly with interop.
One way would be to open the file using a shell command and then hook into the process to work with it. But I found this too messy.

Instead, I decided to use google's Chart API. This does require an internet connection. But that is not a problem for me.

Here is a link for more info: https://sites.google.com/site/e90e50fx/home/generate-qrcode-with-excel

And the VBA code:

```
Option Explicit
'other technical specifications about google chart API:
'https://developers.google.com/chart/infographics/docs/qr_codes

Function URL_QRCode_SERIES( _
    ByVal PictureName As String, _
    ByVal QR_Value As String, _
    Optional ByVal PictureSize As Long = 150, _
    Optional ByVal DisplayText As String = "", _
    Optional ByVal Updateable As Boolean = True) As Variant

Dim oPic As Shape, oRng As Excel.Range
Dim vLeft As Variant, vTop As Variant
Dim sURL As String

Const sRootURL As String = "https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?"
Const sSizeParameter As String = "chs="
Const sTypeChart As String = "cht=qr"
Const sDataParameter As String = "chl="
Const sJoinCHR As String = "&"

If Updateable = False Then
    URL_QRCode_SERIES = "outdated"
    Exit Function
End If

Set oRng = Application.Caller.Offset(, 1)
On Error Resume Next
Set oPic = oRng.Parent.Shapes(PictureName)
If Err Then
    Err.Clear
    vLeft = oRng.Left + 4
    vTop = oRng.Top
Else
    vLeft = oPic.Left
    vTop = oPic.Top
    PictureSize = Int(oPic.Width)
    oPic.Delete
End If
On Error GoTo 0

If Len(QR_Value) = 0 Then
    URL_QRCode_SERIES = CVErr(xlErrValue)
    Exit Function
End If

sURL = sRootURL & _
       sSizeParameter & PictureSize & "x" & PictureSize & sJoinCHR & _
       sTypeChart & sJoinCHR & _
       sDataParameter & UTF8_URL_Encode(VBA.Replace(QR_Value, " ", "+"))

Set oPic = oRng.Parent.Shapes.AddPicture(sURL, True, True, vLeft, vTop, PictureSize, PictureSize)
oPic.Name = PictureName
URL_QRCode_SERIES = DisplayText
End Function


Function UTF8_URL_Encode(ByVal sStr As String)    
    'http://www.nonhostile.com/howto-convert-byte-array-utf8-string-vb6.asp
    Dim i As Long
    Dim a As Long
    Dim res As String
    Dim code As String

    res = ""
    For i = 1 To Len(sStr)
        a = AscW(Mid(sStr, i, 1))
        If a < 128 Then
            code = Mid(sStr, i, 1)
        ElseIf ((a > 127) And (a < 2048)) Then
            code = URLEncodeByte(((a \ 64) Or 192))
            code = code & URLEncodeByte(((a And 63) Or 128))
        Else
            code = URLEncodeByte(((a \ 144) Or 234))
            code = code & URLEncodeByte((((a \ 64) And 63) Or 128))
            code = code & URLEncodeByte(((a And 63) Or 128))
        End If
        res = res & code
    Next i
    UTF8_URL_Encode = res
End Function


Private Function URLEncodeByte(val As Integer) As String
    Dim res As String
    res = "%" & Right("0" & Hex(val), 2)
    URLEncodeByte = res
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You may call the `Calculate` method of the `Worksheet` class each time you need to update the QR code. For example, a raw sketch in VBA:

```
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Sheets("QR_CodeSheet").Calculate
```

Comment: But I am not changing the value of the cell via code. I am only opening the workbook via code and then I am manually changing the value in the cell with the calculation set to automatic. It still doesn't update.

Comment: As a note, I have also tried changing the value in the cell via code and calling `Calculate` and `RefreshAll`, but the QR code still does not respond.

Comment: It seems you need to call any method of the barcode control to update its UI. I'd recommend using the macro recorder available in Excel to see which methods and properties ta call.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. I am changing the cell value by hand. the only difference is how the workbook is opened. Why do i need to call a method of the barcode control, if the workbook is opened via interop, but not if I open it manually? I recorded a macro of me changing the value in the linked cell... but that just gave me a macro which changes the value of the cell, it doesn't do anything to the barcode control directly.

Comment: The macro recorder allows you to generate the required VBA code by doing things manually. See https://support.office.com/en-us/article/automate-tasks-with-the-macro-recorder-974ef220-f716-4e01-b015-3ea70e64937b

Comment: Yes. I am familiar with it. But what do you suggest that I record myself doing manually?

Comment: I have done that but it's not helped. I now have the vba code to add a qr code to a sheet (which I already knew). but i don't need to do that. The QR code is already in the sheet. I just need it to update when the workbook is opened via interop and the cell value is changed. I'm sorry but I am not sure you understand what I am trying to do. Thanks anyway.